# How to add data calculated in python to a 2d numpy array iteratively

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, append

I have defined a 2d numpy array as follows:

```
spectral_array=np.empty((30,2),int) #Importing the Spectral Data
```

This is supposed to create an empty array with 30 rows and 2 columns. The first column should correspond to the "Observation number" and the second number should correspond to "velocities" (these titles are irrelevant and do not need to be printed, its just where I want the final data to end up in the array).

The velocities are calculated via a function which applies a calculation to some given data via a for loop which runs the calculation for each column in the given data as follows:

```
def fit_gauss(x,a,mu,sig,m,c):
        gaus = a*sp.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sig**2))
        line = m*x+c
        return gaus + line
    
#plotting the fit using the gaussian model
for i in range(1, 31): # each iteration i gets a different value, starting with 1 and end with 30
    x = spectral_data[:, 0]
    y = spectral_data[:, i]
#A gaussian fit is applied here, which finds a mean, and that mean is used to calculate the velocity, v below. This is irrelevant to the question but I've just kept it here#
    light_speed=3*10**8
    expect_lambda_square=(656.28*10**-9)**2
    v=-1*((expect_lambda_square*light_speed)-((mu_calc**2)*(light_speed)))/(expect_lambda_square+(mu_calc**2)) #calculating velocity given the mean from the gaussian fits for each observation
    v_kms=v/1000
    print("v is",v_kms, "km/s")
    velocity_database=v_list.append(v_kms) # store velocity of the galaxy at the end of the growing list of velocities
print("The velocities are",v_list)
```

**I would like for these velocities to be inserted into the second column of the 2d numpy array as soon as they are calculated.**

Included in the given data is an "observation number: (number here)" which is the column header for each column used to calculate v. **I must ensure that the observation number corresponds with the velocity that uses its (that specific observation number's) column from the given data for the calculation. This should be printed in the first column of the 2d numpy array, next to its corresponding velocity in the second column**. I have imported the integer value of the observation number from the column header as follows:

```
with open('C:/Users/Sidharth/Documents/Computing Labs/Project 1/Halpha_spectral_data.csv','r') as file:
        line1=file.readline()
        line2=file.readline()
        line1_split=line1.split(',')
        line2_split=line2.split(',')
        str1=('White Space')
        str2=str1.strip()
        
    print(line2_split)
    observation=line2_split
    observation=observation[1:]
    print(observation)
    observation_int = [int(item.split(' ')[1]) for item in observation]
    print(observation_int)
```

I believe the above should go inside the for loop which runs the velocity calculations, so that an observation number can be inserted into the 2d numpy array at the same time as the calculated velocity.

At the end I should be able to order the 2d numpy array by ascending observation number.

Comment: `alist=[]` and `alist.append(...)` is a good way of building a list itertively.  It should not be imitated with arrays.  Assigning values to elements (or better yet slices) of a predefined array is valid (but don't call it appending).  Creating the array with `np.empty((n,m))` is ok if you will assign all elements; I prefer `np.zeros`.

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted the title accordingly.